# Broadcast Receiver not processing SMS's

Tags: android, service, sms, broadcastreceiver

I've seen on SO that @Commonsware states that all that is needed to receive SMS's is a Broadcast Receiver (i.e., *without* the use of a service).  I'd like to employ that approach since it makes sense to me.  Unfortunately it does not appear as if SMS's are being received/processed in my Broadcast Receiver.  The apk is being installed successfully but no log entries are being generated when I send test SMS's.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's the Manifest:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.oheller.pete2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_broadcastreceiver"
        android:label="@string/sms_broadcastreceiver"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.eagleeyeactionbar" >

        <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver_Test" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <provider
            android:name=".contentprovider.GPSTrackerContentProvider"
            android:authorities="net.oheller.pete2.contentprovider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:multiprocess="true"
            android:permission="true" >
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's the SMS Receiver code.  It's purpose is to collect data via SMS's and write a record of each to the content provider (SQLite database).

```
public class SMSReceiver_Test extends BroadcastReceiver { 
TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
String deviceCountryCode = "";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Get the SMS message passed in from the intent
    Bundle SMSmessageContent = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] receivedSMS = null;
    String returnStr = "";
    Long current_time_stamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    String curTimeString = getFormattedDate(current_time_stamp, "dd-MMM-yy h:mma");     

    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);       

    String incoming_SMSphone_number = "";
    String SMSmsgText = "";
    long timeStamp = current_time_stamp;

    if (SMSmessageContent != null) {  // [IF valid SMS]
        //Retrieve the SMS message info
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) SMSmessageContent.get("pdus");
        receivedSMS = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i=0; i<receivedSMS.length; i++) {  // [FOR get SMS content]
            receivedSMS[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            incoming_SMSphone_number = receivedSMS[i].getOriginatingAddress().toString().trim();
            SMSmsgText = receivedSMS[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            returnStr += curTimeString +"\n";

Log.d("EagleEye", String.format("SMSReciever: SMS=\"%s\"", SMSmsgText))  ;  ///DEBUG
        }  // [ENDFOR get SMS content]

            ///////////////////////////
            // prepare values for insertion into the SQLite DB
                ContentValues GPSTrackValues = new ContentValues();
                GPSTrackValues.put(GPSTrackerTable.COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER, incoming_SMSphone_number);
                GPSTrackValues.put(GPSTrackerTable.COLUMN_TIME_STAMP, timeStamp);

 //// Prepare access to content provider
                Uri GPSuri = GPSTrackerContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_GPS_Tracks; //specify the content provider location
                ContentResolver GPSTrackCR = context.getContentResolver();          

                // Insert new entry into DB
                Uri insertURI = GPSTrackCR.insert(GPSuri, GPSTrackValues);      
Log.d("EagleEye", "DB insert results="+insertURI)  ;  ////////DEBUG

    }  // [ENDIF Valid SMS] 
}  // [END onReceive]
   }  // [END SMSReceiver]
```

Comment: So you mean you are not getting the broadcast of the received sms or you are not receiveing the sms itself.?

Comment: I am not getting the broadcast.  I am receiving the SMS.  BTW, the SMSReceiver was taken from an activity where it was working when the activity was on screen.  The problem was when the activity was off screen the SMSReceiver no longer received the broadcasts.  That's why I am trying this new approach to separate the receiver from the activity.  Is there a better way to go?

Comment: @AndersMetnik: good idea.  I just reviewed the answers and accepted one.  I wish I could have accepted more!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code seems to me correct.
You can try by increasing the priority by max ..

```
 <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
```

There may be case , when other receiver is getting sms before yours and aborting them.

Comment: Eureka!  setting android:priority="2147483647" did it.  Thank you.  (btw, where did you find that impressive number?)

Comment: Yes...Its simple.. Higher numbers have a higher priority. priorites have been increased to 2^31 - 1 ,as the compressed xml format represents the number as a 4 byte signed integer.

Comment: I could not understand exactly ,but Its really not necessary to have a launcher activity in an application . There could be only receiver even . so..I doubt this is something different problem...!!

Answer (score 1):

Your priority might not be good enough, try setting it to 2147483647.

```
    <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver_Test" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

After doing that, try start it in debug mode, and breakpoint in your onReceive method, or make a `Log.i("BroadcastSMSReceiver", "Received something in SMSRECEIVERTEST")` :)

Edit, set priority to a high number instead of 1, just read that high number equals higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `android:priority` attribute

Comment: Do explain a little but more about why ?

Comment: @mtk: please see my comments above.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: developer guild says "Use this attribute only if you really need to impose a specific order in which the broadcasts are received, or want to force Android to prefer one activity over others."

I was playing with ANDROID SMS api and developed a test project that receives SMS and my manifest code block is just 
        <receiver
            android:name=".IHSmsRecieved"
            android:label="Sms is Recieved" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

and that did the work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on android developer doc  must be -1000>priority<1000 thus highest priority of intent-filter is 999