# How to make my SMS App is highest Priority to receive Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android-broadcast

*At First, I am sorry for my English is not good enough !*

My problem is i am writting a Block SMS Application and i want to receive sms with my app and then i abort broadcast to make default sms app can't receive SMS, so i set my app have a highest priority (1000), but my app still receive broadcast after default sms app of android.

I print all of my Android Phone SMS's broadcast received signal in order when my phone receive a SMS and i recognize that The System SMS App alway receive SMS Broadcast first and it also have Highest priority.

So how can i make my sms app could receive SMS Broadcast before Default SMS of system ?

I am really needed your help !

Thank for your reading !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Broadcast Receiver not processing SMS's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395925/broadcast-receiver-not-processing-smss)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As documented by Google, the maximum priority for a broadcast receiver is less than 1000, literally 999.
But you can set it to a maximum level of 2147483647. As other apps on Google Play uses higher priority (more than 999) than your Broadcast receiver, due to this your app may not receive the SMS. By this maximum level, your app will always receive the SMS first.
So this way you can get broadcast before the default messaging app.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395925/broadcast-receiver-not-processing-smss) answer!

---

### Edit

I was revisiting my old answers on StackOverflow and this answer looked sketchy. The following is an excerpt from the [official documentation of IntentFilter priority](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element#priority).

> The priority that should be given to the parent component with regard to handling intents of the type described by the filter. This attribute has meaning for both activities and broadcast receivers:
>
> 1. It provides information about how able an activity is to respond to an intent that matches the filter, relative to other activities that could also respond to the intent. When an intent could be handled by multiple activities with different priorities, Android will consider only those with higher priority values as potential targets for the intent.
> 2. It controls the order in which broadcast receivers are executed to receive broadcast messages. Those with higher priority values are called before those with lower values. (The order applies only to synchronous messages; it's ignored for asynchronous messages.)

The official [lower and upper limits are still -1000 and 1000 respectively](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter#SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY). Broadcast receivers with higher priority can [abort ordered broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver#abortBroadcast()), hence, preventing other receivers with a lower priority from receiving them.

Comment: ashu I set it to maximum level of `2147483647` but still not working. Android 6.0

Comment: @AsifMushtaq probably because some other app in the device already registered a receiver with this priority 2147483647 ?? After all everybody have access to this answer.